# Cakephp: Load components in components

Tags: cakephp

in app_controller.php  load Session, Auth components.

And in posts_controller.php,  i use CustomComponent with $components = array('Session','Auth');

Then do CustomComponent must reload Session, Auth components?

if i use and create much components and that components use other components .It will make  app is very slow?

---

I asked in cakephp IRC, A person answer is not:

> [11:05]  it will not be slow, I believe it passes those around via reference
>
> [11:05]  so you have nothing to worry about

Answer (score 7):

Lets say you want to import BComponent into AComponent.

AComponent

```
class AComponent extends Component {
     public $components = array('BComponent');

     public function xyz(){
           $test = $this->BComponent->abc($name);
           echo $test;
     }
}
```

BComponent

```
class BComponent extends Component {

     public function abc($name){
           return "My name is: ". $name;
     }
}
```

Comment: How does that work if you need to pass a configuration array into BComponent which is interpenetrated in a initialize() call for BComponent?

Answer (score 3):

yes, it would need to be `$components = array('Session','Auth','Custom');` Or you can use: `App::import('Component', 'Custom');$Custom = new CustomComponent();`

`Then do CustomComponent must reload Session, Auth components?` If you don't use Session or Auth inside your CustomComponent class, then no.

`It will make app is very slow?` No, unless you use a lot of components.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another answers here but this is the only way it works for me

Imagine that we have two components

1 - IntegrationsComponent

2 - ProcessComponent

And we want to use IntegrationsComponent  inside ProcessComponent, so in this last component we have to call the component using this way

```
App::uses('ComponentCollection', 'Controller');
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
App::uses('IntegrationsComponent', 'Controller/Component'); 

class ProcessComponent extends Component {

// Method of this component where we call another component method inside of it
    
public function methodForCallingAnotherComponent() {
    
    // Initialize component
      
    $collection = new ComponentCollection();
    $this->IntegrationsComponent = new IntegrationsComponent($collection);
    
    // You can pass properties' component if it has
    
    $this->IntegrationsComponent->create = false;
    $this->IntegrationsComponent->type = 'UPDATE_PRODUCT';
                    
    // Call method of the component
    $this->IntegrationsComponent->ecommercePublish();
    
    }
    
}
```